# How do I use font descriptors in the Title of UINavigationBar like in Apple's Notes and Reminders apps?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, nsattributedstring

I've been able to use these font descriptors in an attributed string. I'd like to be able to use them in the title of the Navigation Bar (in Apple Dev's old DrillDownSave sample code). I'm trying:

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize window, outlineData, navigationController, savedLocation, titleTextAttributes;

- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
                                  NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor purpleColor],
                                          NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle,
                                                NSKernAttributeName : @4,
                                      ;
                                            }
```

I'm getting "Unexpected interface name 'NSDictionary': expected expression" and "Expected expression" (seemingly concerning that last semi-colon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a variable inside of method call. You should call it like this!

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor purpleColor],
                                                               NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle,
                                                                     NSKernAttributeName : @4}];

}
```

UPDATE:

You could call it in your app delegate in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self customizeAppearance];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! No errors. But also not applying font descriptors to the title of the UINavigationBar. Do I need to change something in the AppDelegate.h?

Comment: Where are you calling it?

Comment: Sorry! I'm really brand new. DrillDownSave has only one UINavigationBar so I was trying to add this to AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m because UINavigationBar is in Navigation Controller, which references AppDelegate.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! I have to take a break now (unfortunately), but the latest is that the app screen went white with a black bar at the bottom. Maybe because I already have - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application ?

Comment: You should only have one and the one with options is better

Comment: @Moxy The `NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle` isn't working for me.. The effect doesn't show. The other attributes are working though. Is it possible that this effect is disabled for `UINavigationBar`'s? I can't find anything elsewhere.

Comment: @sti are you using it on iOS 7?

Comment: @Moxy Yes. Letterpress never applied to the default label in titleView, so I replaced it with a custom UILabel. I still have a couple of problems though.. The letterpress-effect is now somehow inverted. There's a white 'shadow' instead of a black one. I've read other people having this issue when there's a custom color/image behind the label, which I have. The other issue is that whenever I navigate to a view now, the custom label is placing itself on the far left side of the NavigationBar during the push-animation. Ever seen this issue?